# Why is the 3'UTR region highly methylated in most of the human genes?

Tags: dna, epigenetics

Most of the human genes are found to be highly methylated in their 3'UTR region (0.8-0.9%). I was wondering if there is any specific reason for this?

Comment: any reference? would be interested to see it...

Answer (score 8):

According to [Choi et al. Genome Biology 2009, 10:R89](http://genomebiology.com/2009/10/9/R89), DNA methylation at both coding boundaries may regulate transcription elongation and stabilize splicing by reducing the occurrences of exon skipping.

From the abstract:

> Here we report a genome-wide observation of distinct peaks of
>   nucleosomes and methylation at both ends of a protein coding unit.
>   Elongating polymerases tend to pause near both coding ends immediately
>   upstream of the epigenetic peaks, causing a significant reduction in
>   elongation efficiency. Conserved features in underlying protein coding
>   sequences seem to dictate their evolutionary conservation across
>   multiple species. The nucleosomal and methylation marks are commonly
>   associated with high sequence-encoded DNA-bending propensity but
>   differentially with CpG density. As the gene grows longer, the
>   epigenetic codes seem to be shifted from variable inner sequences
>   toward boundary regions, rendering the peaks more prominent in higher
>   organisms.

Their data (figures 1 and S2), however, do not support a generalized increase in the 3' UTR regions in either human T cells, mouse liver, yeast or flies.

Comment: Thank you so much. This paper looks very interesting. I will read it and see if I have more to discuss.